# When I try to add a folder to the archive get an error: the path is too long

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

I using .Net Framework 4.0; VS 2015; Ionic.Zip.Reduced (DotNetZip.Reduced) v1.9.1.8. When I try to add a folder to the archive get an exception with the text:

> The path is too long

Sample code:

```
using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
{
  zipFile.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
  zipFile.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
  zipFile.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  zipFile.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;

  var dirPath = @"C:\AAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\";
  zipFile.AddDirectory(dirPath);  <-Exception
  zipFile.Save();
}
```

In the folder is a file named:                    `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.zip`

As a result of an error:

> The path is too long

Rewritten in the file-based addition to the archive (using a relative path):

```
using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
{
  zipFile.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
  zipFile.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
  zipFile.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  zipFile.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;

  var dirPath = @"C:\AAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\";
  Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

  foreach (var fullFilePath in files)
  {
     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);
     var relatedPath = fullFilePath.Substring(0, fullFilePath.LastIndexOf(fileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Replace(zipDir, "");
     var relatedFilePath = Path.Combine(relatedPath, fileName);

     zipFile.AddFile(relatedFilePath);   <-Exception
  }
  zipFile.Save();
}
```

The error is the same:

> The path is too long

I tried to call `Path.GetDirectoryName()` method, but it also returns an error:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I found a lot of solutions but to get to work and did not work (because of the specifics of the application to the new version Framework'a can not go).

- Use Framework 4.6.2. Set `UseLegacyPathHandling = false` [option](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/09/new-net-path-handling-sneak-peek/) in `App.Config` or `Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling = false; Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths = false`
- With the mention of a Group Policy and the inclusion of the option Configuration> Administrative Templates> System> Filesystem> [Enable NTFS long paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#namespaces), or to enable the option via the manifest `<ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>`
- Use the prefix `\\?\` [In the path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) (I understand that for the new version of Framework)
- Convert path to the file in 8.3 format using [GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) function .... (Error remains)

Maybe someone faced such problem. I will be glad to any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a path shorter than 248 characters?

Comment: @JayGould Yes. Works fine.

Comment: Sorry I was being sarcastic. If your directory is over 248 characters there's not work around, you need a directory that isn't over the limit.

Comment: I can't  change catalog. I try add to archive user folder. There can be any directory structure. Is that where that copy to a temporary folder. However, the data may be several gigabytes

Comment: Well, you basically have two options - one is to iterate the folder structure yourself and build the catalog manually instead of relying on the `ZipFile.AddDirectory`, another to find a different zip library (you could try the one included in .NET). Sadly, many applications still don't support long paths, so a lot of the infrastructure has to be very conservative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your path is too long there's not much you can do about it. Even if you can move Windows limits a step further your application won't work well on a non ad-hoc configured system in that scenario.

You can workaround copying the files you have to work with to a temp folder like C:\temp and add the files to the archive from there.

You can even mimic the same folder tree structure with directory names composed of only 1 or 2 letters and then map the complete (but really shorter) directory path to the original path somewhere (on a file for example), so that you can rebuild the original folder tree structure with the same names later on.

Comment: Yes, I want to save it as a folder structure for further data recovery.